# Using MimeKit to cms sign and verify

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, mimekit

I am using Mimekit to do rsa pss cms sign, to simulate this openssl command
openssl cms -sign -in keys.zip -binary -nodetach -signer selfsigned.crt -inkey keypair.pem -out keys.zip.signed -keyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss

```
    public byte[] Sign(byte[] data, byte[] signCert, byte[] privateKey, CmsKeyOpt cmsKeyOpt)
            {
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage
                {
                    Body = new MimePart()
                    {
                        Content = new MimeContent(new MemoryStream(data)),
                        ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Binary,
                    },
                };
    
                // Load private key from byte array
                StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(privateKey), Encoding.Default);
                AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(stream).ReadObject();
    
                // load certifacte from byte array
                X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
                X509Certificate certificate = parser.ReadCertificate(signCert);
    
                // Create RSA PSS CMS signer
                CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner(certificate, keyPair.Private)
                {
                    RsaSignaturePadding = RsaSignaturePadding.Pss,
                    DigestAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithm.Sha256,
                };
    
                // Create BouncyCastle Secure MimeContext 
                BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext ctx = new TemporarySecureMimeContext();
                ctx.EncapsulatedSign(signer, new MemoryStream(data));
    
                // Get signed message body and override it
                message.Body = MultipartSigned.Create(ctx, signer, message.Body);
    
                byte[] singedData;
                using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    message.WriteTo(memory);
                    singedData = memory.ToArray();
                }
                return singedData;
            }
```

And everything works fine, my question how I can achieve verify by Mimekit/BouncyCastle, to simulate this openssl command
openssl cms -verify -in keys.zip.signed.dec -CAfile selfsigned.crt -out keys_dec_unsigned.zip

I tried this but I got exception System.NotSupportedException: 'SQLite is not available on pkcs7.Verify(out original) line

```
 public byte[] Verify(byte[] data, byte[] signCert, byte[] privateKey)
        {
            bool valid = false;
            // Load private key from byte array
            StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(privateKey), Encoding.Default);
            AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = (AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)new PemReader(stream).ReadObject();

            // load certifacte from byte array
            X509CertificateParser parser = new X509CertificateParser();
            X509Certificate certificate = parser.ReadCertificate(signCert);

            MimeMessage message = MimeMessage.Load(new MemoryStream(data));
            // Create BouncyCastle Secure MimeContext 
            MimeEntity original;
            ApplicationPkcs7Mime pkcs7 = message.Body as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
            if (pkcs7 != null && pkcs7.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.SignedData)
            {
                foreach (var signature in pkcs7.Verify(out original))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        valid = signature.Verify();
                    }
                    catch (DigitalSignatureVerifyException)
                    {
                        // There was an error verifying the signature.
                    }
                }
            }


            byte[] res = { 0 };
            return res;
        }
```

Is there any guide I can follow to verify and return the data to it's origin forum, or an example?

Answer (score 1):

By default, MimeKit tries to instantiate a S/MIME verify context based on its SQLite backend for certificate storage.

If you don't have SQLite installed and/or don't have your certificates stored in the SQLite database that MimeKit will maintain for you, then you need to either register a different backend for certificate storage/retrieval or instantiate your own S/MIME context (like you did for signing).

MimeKit comes with 2 options:

- [TemporarySecureMimeContext](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Cryptography_TemporarySecureMimeContext.htm) which stores certificates in memory and is what you used to sign the message in your code snippet above.
- [WindowsSecureMimeContext](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/T_MimeKit_Cryptography_WindowsSecureMimeContext.htm) which uses the Windows OS X.509 certificate store.

Once you decide on which of those to use, you will need to import your certificate(s) into the context (which will import them into the appropriate backend storage location).

Then, after that, you can do this:

```
using (BouncyCastleSecureMimeContext ctx = new TemporarySecureMimeContext()) {
    ctx.Import (...);

    foreach (var signature in pkcs7.Verify(ctx, out original)) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Update:**

This devolved into misuse of the openssl cms sign command and an inability to verify the signature using MimeKit because MimeKit expects the encapsulated signed data to be in MIME format as it is supposed to be according to the S/MIME specifications.

Here's the deal:

The openssl cms sign command can be used to sign arbitrary data and the corresponding openssl cms verify command can be used to verify such signed output. HOWEVER, it is only valid S/MIME if the original content signed by the openssl cms sign command is/was in MIME format.

MimeKit expects valid S/MIME because it is... surprise, surprise... a MIME library.

As you might have noticed, the Verify() method has an output parameter (`out MimeEntity originalEntity`). This means that the Verify() method extracts the encapsulated content from within the signed data and parses it into a MIME entity and returns it to you, the caller, in the form of said output parameter.

If the encapsulated content is not in MIME format, then, obviously, the parser will fail to parse it.

**Additional background with how CMS signatures work:**

When you sign content using the CMS signing routine (e.g. `openssl cms sign ...`), it produces something that looks a bit like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 

MIIQgAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIQcTCCEG0CAQExDTALBglghkgBZQMEAgEwggkPBgkq...
```

The base64 content in the above MIME part includes both the original content *and* the CMS signature data (i.e. a list of signatures).

Therefor, MimeKit's Verify() method needs to separate the signatures from the original content after base64 decoding it. MimeKit then returns to you, the caller, the original content (which it expects to be in MIME format) *and* the list of signatures that you can then independently verify the authenticity of.

When I kept repeating myself that it mattered what format the `file.bin` file was in when you signed the content, I was *not* saying that openssl or MimeKit needed to parse `file.bin` when verifying the signature, I was saying that `file.bin` has exactly the same content as what would be extracted from the base64 blob in the S/MIME output produced by `openssl cms sign ...` and *therefore*, it needs to be in MIME format.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I achieved it but it gives me another exception says System.FormatException : Failed to parse entity headers in pkcs7.Verify(ctx, out original). with knowing that I already generate the signed file with openssl command above, link to my code in https://pastebin.com/WKBUVuKB

Comment: any ideas why this happened?

Comment: Because the signed data isn’t MIME like it is supposed to be?

Comment: How this can be happened as I generated the signed data with the openssl command mentioned in the question, and this is the first part of signed file by open ssl

Comment: MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name="smime.p7m"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIIQgAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIQcTCCEG0CAQExDTALBglghkgBZQMEAgEwggkPBgkq....

Comment: If the file you signed with OpenSSL was not in MIME format, then you will get the error you are seeing.

Comment: Something wrong I followed every step you mentioned, here is my openessl command that sign the file:  openssl cms -sign -in file.bin -binary -nodetach -outform SMIME -signer selfsigned.crt -inkey keypair.pem -out file.bin.signed -keyopt rsa_padding_mode:pss
Mimekit will always throw error, I believe there is something wrong, did you check my code snippet, I followed the instructions and the signed file get the header with smime data, but the Mimekit not working!!

Comment: It doesn’t matter what the OpenSSL command is. What matters is the format of file.bin. Is it in MIME format? I’m betting it’s not.

Comment: In other words, MimeEntity.Load(“file.bin”) needs to work or verifying file.bin.signed can never work.

Comment: I am confused, the verifying process is based on the signed file not the source file, so basically, I should care about the signed file not the source of the input, in other words the signed file in mime format, and that what should I care about!

Comment: But the Verify() method extracts the original content and tries to parse it into a MimeEntity. Hence the parse failure if the original content is not in MIME format.

Comment: The verifying process in openssl cares about (signed file, certificate ) that's it, it doesn't ask about the source of signed file, btw the signed file in smime format, and also here is the header of the signed file

MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m" Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=signed-data; name="smime.p7m" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 MIIQgAYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoIIQcTCCEG0CAQExDTALBglghkgBZQMEAgEwggkPBgkq....

Comment: BTW, I am doing both sign/verify with openssl and works fine, file.bin without caring about format of that file, I deal with it as a binary file, and also the Mimekit able to sign the file and open verify success when, I try to sign with openssl and verify with Mimekit the error occurs!

Comment: The OpenSSL sign command may not care about the input file format, but the S/MIME specifications require the input format to be MIME otherwise there’s no way for mail software to know what to do with it. Don’t assume that just because an OpenSSL command allows it that it is the correct thing to do. The OpenSSL sign command is just a general purpose signing operation.

Comment: You are not allowed to talk with me in this way "How many times do I need to explain it to you?", whatever if I am missing something or not!

Comment: @MostafaHassan I am trying to help you and you kept asking the same question that I have answered over and over. Stop asking me the same question and just accept the fact that I’m right. I know what I’m talking about.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong in any way, I am not aware of this, just it, I don't mind all your answer, they were helpful, but you shouldn't talk like this with anyone who doesn't get your point, we all sometimes get confused about we are trying to achieve! Anyway thanks for your support

Comment: I've updated my answer. Perhaps my latest explanation will finally make what I was saying over and over again more clear. It's unfortunately very difficult to type long winded explanations on my phone (and even more difficult to do in the comment section which limits text to ~500 characters).